# static CArray C++ MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I simply cannot seem to be able to make a static CArray and work with it.

Here's my code:

```
class WhiteBoard
{
public:

    static CArray<WhiteBoard, WhiteBoard> test;

    void tester()
    {
        test.Add(*this);
    }
};
```

And upon calling the tester method, I get an unresolved external symbol.
Full error code is:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static class CArray<class WhiteBoard,class WhiteBoard> WhiteBoard::test" (?test@WhiteBoard@@2V?$CArray@VWhiteBoard@@V1@@@A) MFCApplication2 C:\Users\sw.eng\source\repos\MFCApplication2\MFCApplication2Dlg.obj 1
```

This is my first time working with CArray but I messed around with CArray of int and all worked alright.

Could it be that I'm trying to have a CArray of WhiteBoard inside of WhiteBoard? (I do need this functionality to keep track of all child objects made, which is why I do it)

Removing the `static` keyword makes everything run. But then it's not a static member, and I need it to be one.

Anyways, all help would be incredible and very much appreciated.

EDIT 1:

I've made another class which I called BoardBoss.
WhiteBoard inherits BoardBoss.
CArray is now of BoardBoss type. CArray<BoardBoss, BoardBoss> test;

The issue persists.

Comment: Your syntax is merely *declaring* the static member, hence the link error.  Look here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static class members need to be defined. As posted, the `WhiteBoard` class merely declares the identifier `test`. That makes the compiler happy, but the linker fails, because it cannot find the referenced symbol when it is used.

To fix this you need to add the following to a compilation unit:

```cpp
CArray<WhiteBoard, WhiteBoard> Whiteboard::test;
```